# My website crashes when trying to use active directory instead of ADFS, what should I do?

Tags: c#, adfs

I have some code that was working when just using active directory,however, when publishing it gives an error.

//Allow Active Directory Credentials to remove someone from the global unsubscribe

```
    protected void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain"))
        {

            // find the group in question
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "IT Group");

            if (group != null)
            { // remove user}
```

This now crashes the webpage and i get the following error:

Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Principal user can't be used with ASP.NET forms instead you must use a claims form and check your claims/roles.

```
    // Cast the Thread.CurrentPrincipal
        ClaimsPrincipal icp = User as ClaimsPrincipal;

   // Access IClaimsIdentity which contains claims
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)icp.Identity;

  // what we are doing here is using a for each to get to the claim         
        foreach (Claim claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
        {
 //The claim we are looking for is in this directory /groupsid
            if (claim.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/groupsid")
            {
 //We use a for loop to go through this because it reads it like a JSON and will either pull the first or last
//Basic for loop incrementing until it finds our group (IT ALL)
                for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
                {
//If our claim contains IT ALL (which it does) then do something...
                    if (claim.Value.Contains("Name of Group"))
                    {
//I'm storing the result here so we can call it otherwise we lose it...
lblResultq.Text = (claim.Value.ToString());
```

Hope this will help someone in the future!